# Selenium FirefoxDriver getText - UTF-8 encoding

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, encoding, selenium-firefoxdriver

I searched the web for quit some time, and i can't figure it out.

While using **Selenium** with the **FirefoxDriver**,
can't perform actions on the text cuz i keep getting ???? instead of actual characters.

*Source file example:*

[image]

*Java code:*

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I have tried to use some profiles i found online - did not work.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( <something>, <something> );
profile.setPreference( <something>, <something> );
driver = new FirefoxDriver( profile );
```

I think the problem is in the **default encoding of Firefox**, witch is "western".
and **i need it to be "UTF-8"** , or changing according to the site.

All answers to the questions i saw, did not solve the problem.

Comment: yeah its hard form information provided please can you provide actual htl source code

Comment: Could you show screenshot of web that Firefox has rendered?

Comment: [link](http://yedion.afeka.ac.il/yedion/fireflyweb.aspx?prgname=login)
  this is the site .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm 99% certain this is simply a matter of the OP not having a Hebrew font installed ([e.g.](http://www.sbl-site.org/educational/BiblicalFonts_SBLHebrew.aspx)) on their client machine.

After a bit of detective work, [this site](http://yedion.yvc.ac.il) seems very close to the site being tested. It's not *exactly* the same, but I think it shows the difference having the right font has.

[image]

Of course, not having the right font doesn't stop you validating the server's output.

```
@Test
public void testHebrew() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://yedion.yvc.ac.il");
    Assert.assertEquals( driver.getTitle(), "תחנת מידע לסטודנט המכללה האקדמית עמק יזרעאל");
}
```

is a quick way to verify that the server's output is correct, even if your web-client of choice can't render said output.

Comment: the Hebrew font is OK when i'm using the site.

the problem is when i activate selenium - the source code is all question marks where the Hebrew characters suppose to be.

Comment: and yes, it's practically the same site. [link](http://yedion.afeka.ac.il/yedion/fireflyweb.aspx?prgname=login)

Comment: Irrespective of what the content looks like in *View Source*, have you tried running my working test (above)? Your page reports a Content-Type of UTF8 (which overrides any browser defaults), which should match the Java Unicode chars in my example. You shouldn't need any workarounds/hacks to test Unicode sites end-to-end.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have done a work around for the question the idea is that

```
1.First take all value inside the list(here i think you are getting ???? instead of actual charterers .)
2.Now save all values inside the text document which save all value in UTF-8 format
3.Now read those values from the text file (now they will print the way they are in web app)
4. Now perform your next operation
```

5.i have attached a sample piece of working code please have a look

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\eclipseProject\\StackOverFlow\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Ftab%3Dwm");

        // below in the right corner there is a Drop-down with values of languages for different country
        // take them all inside the list
        List<WebElement> myddval = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='lang-chooser']/option"));
        System.out.println(myddval.size());

        // print the last value inside the dd on to the console
        System.out.println("DD value before Change (ANSI format) : "+ myddval.get(myddval.size()-1).getText()); // will print ???? in the console
        // now create a text document which saves its content form ANSI to UTF-8 format
        writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\name.txt", "UTF-8");
        // writing only the last value form dd in the text document = 繁體中文
        writer.write(myddval.get(myddval.size()-1).getText());
        System.out.println("value in the dd is : " + myddval.get(myddval.size()-1).getText());
        writer.close();
        // reading the value and printing it in the console now it will print =  繁體中文
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\rajnish\\Desktop\\name.txt"));
        System.out.println("Reading Text after converting it to UTF-8 Encoding : "+ bufferedReader.readLine());

        // now performing some action
        driver.findElement(By.id("lang-chooser")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        myddval.get(myddval.size()-1).click();

    }
```

Comment: great idea, already tried something similar. sadly, not working for  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); .

Comment: thanks @sahar Milis i have not tried with firefox but i think it will work for firefox even